# Prove that the function admits a maximum and minimum

Tags: functions, proof-verification, continuity

Given the function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)= x^3+x^2+cosx+19$, prove that the function admits a maximum and minimum in the given domain $[0,1]$.

Hint: you may assume without proving it that polynomials and $cosx$ are continuous
functions on $\mathbb{R}$. $[5]$

I'm assuming I need to prove this is continuous then use the Weierstrass Extreme Value Theorem? Not really sure how to show this or even if that is the correct way of proving it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because $f$ it's a continuous function on the compact $[0,1]$. It's all!

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is right.  You're allowed to use that polynomials are continuous, so $h(x) = x^{3} + x^{2} + 19$ is continuous.  You can also use that $r(x) = \cos(x)$ is continuous.  Now notice that $f(x)$ is really $h(x) + r(x)$.  Since $h$ and $r$ are continuous, their sum is continuous (you should prove this if you don't know it: if $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are continuous functions, then $f_{1} + f_{2}$ is a continuous function).

Thus, since $f(x)$ is continuous, and its domain is a compact (closed and bounded) set, then the extreme value theorem gives that it attains a max an a min.